# How to get AD user and manager details in a single report using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, merge, active-directory

$a contains user details like (name,samaccountname,empid,manager,etc) , $b contains managers details like (name,employeeID), I am not sure how to get these details in a csv file

expected output

```
username samaccountname empid managername manageremployeeID
abc       a.bc          1234  xyz         5678
```

code:

```
$a=Get-aduser -identity "abc" -properties * |select name,samaccountname,empid,manager
$b=Get-aduser -identity $a.manager -properties * | select name,empid**
```

I am getting both $a and $b, but I want to get both $a and $b in a single csv file which i am failing to do it.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop and [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3) to create a single object having the joined properties of the queried user with its Manager:

```bash
Get-ADUser 'abc' -Properties empid, manager | ForEach-Object {
    $manager = $null
    try {
        $manager = Get-ADUser $_.manager -Properties empid
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        username          = $_.name
        samaccountname    = $_.samaccountname
        empid             = $_.empid
        managerName       = $manager.name
        managerEmployeeId = $manager.empid
    } 
} | Export-Csv pathhere.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

As aside, for a single user it wouldn't really matter but if you're going to do this for many users try to avoid the use of `-Properties *`, querying all user's attributes is very inefficient, you should always add the attributes you need as shown in above example. `name` and `samaccountname` are not included in this case because both attributes are returned by default by `Get-ADUser`.

Comment: when I use the above code for many users , the output file (export csv) is overwriting the older output data, how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: @Swasthik you can use `-Append` with `Export-Csv`

Comment: foreach($ou in $OUsToSearch)
{
$XXXUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter "enabled -eq 'true'" -Properties * -SearchBase $ou

foreach($user in $XXXUsers)
{Added your code here
}

Comment: @Swasthik no, adding my code inside that loop is very inefficient. please ask a new question adding this information and reference this answer. there is a much better / easier way to re-use this code targeting all enabled accounts